# Hardware level features access in Android

Tags: android, hardware

My main question is how low level(hardware level) access to a device's features is provided by Android? For example, can I get access to very detailed communicative properties on a device? what is a good reference for that? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All features are aviable using the java API, but the NDK is more "low level".

Comment: By low I didn't mean lower level programming, I meant the most basic measurements for example the phase of the received signal.

Comment: well, android is based on a linux kernel, so you basically can do everything linux can do, access the files in /dev, and, if the driver supports it, measure the phase of a recieved signal.

Answer (score 0):

You can go as low as necessary. You can access all input retrieved and perceived by the device (You may refer to the android.* libraries for this or use NDK as suggested). 
However, it is mainly up to you to interpret the input.
It was mentioned the "phase of a received signal". You would have to process the signal before you can retrieve its phase. So if you have some USB device sending you some kind of signal, you could use the Android.hardware.usb (among with the other options afore mentioend) to help you retrieve the input, treat the signal (build or find some java DSP libraries), and voilá ! 
You got yourself all the information you wish. 
In a short summary, the tools are there.